# Get correct indentation when pasting in VS Code

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

Create a new HTML document in Visual Studio Code then paste this:

```
<body>
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li>Foo</li>
            <li>Bar</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
```

Copy the `<ul></ul>` statement. 
Insert a new line after `</ul>`.

```
<body>
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li>Foo</li>
            <li>Bar</li>
        </ul>
        | <-- cursor    
    </div>
</body>
```

... then paste.

```
<body>
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li>Foo</li>
            <li>Bar</li>
        </ul>
        <ul>
                <li>Foo</li>
                <li>Bar</li>
            </ul>        
    </div>
</body>
```

The indentation is completely messed up. A tons of related question are answering this question with:

> Disable the `"editor.formatOnPaste": true`, from your settings.

The fact is that I have already disabled this feature. Otherwise I would have got  even worse:

```
<body>
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li>Foo</li>
            <li>Bar</li>
        </ul>
<ul>
    <li>Foo</li>
    <li>Bar</li>
</ul>
    </div>
</body>
```

Is there a way to just paste what I copied AS-IS or either get a correct formatting such as:

```
<body>
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li>Foo</li>
            <li>Bar</li>
        </ul>
        <ul>
            <li>Foo</li>
            <li>Bar</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
```

Please the <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> is not an answer because it will format the whole document and it requires additional operations.

Comment: have you tried CTRL + Shift + V for auto-formatting pasted code?

Comment: Yes and it does the same as  when `editor.formatOnPaste` is set to `true`

Comment: Just tried it and it works fine with me if I set formatOnPaste to false. I suspect some plugin is taking precedence.

Comment: i am lookin for same answer, the vscode is good. but its indent pasting is very messed up. leave php, it doenst  even work for pure html files properly.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Currently there is no known stable solution to this. i myself am searching from weeks now. there are some plugins for paste and indent but they raise different issues in many other things like non-responding paste, slow pasting or no multicursor support.

The VSCode forum has this issue as open from years but they arent very active on it.
Please go visit the official issue page and try commenting there, every single one counts and we may get official solution to this.
https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/32320

Additionally you can try below plugins, may work for you.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Rubymaniac.vscode-paste-and-indent
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=gazugafan.vscode-indent-on-paste

Comment: Issue was lock-botted. :(

Answer (score 16):

Thanks to @Galzor for pointing out the issue. Scrolling through Github issues I got workaround for this issue without any additional extension.

1. Press CTRL+Z after copy paste. It will give you correct indentation. (It works with PasteOnFormat option disabled.)
2. Or change editing file's language mode to `PLAIN TEXT` then paste. (You can find language mode in bottom right corner in VS Code) It will not mess up indentation. Then change back language mode to original again.

Hope it helps someone and gets fixed soon!

Comment: Unfortunately, `ctrl+z` does not work when pasting multiple lines because it fixes only the first one.

Comment: @sdlins this does not seem to be true – or it was fixed recently, because it worked well with all lines for me just now

Comment: cmd+z only changes the first line for me.

Answer (score 3):

No one has mentioned this, but it solved my indentation issues, which I still had even when `"editor.formatOnPaste"` is false.

Look for Auto Indent in settings. Auto Indent controls whether the editor should automatically adjust the indentation when users type, paste, move or indent lines.

Set `"editor.autoIndent": "none"` and that should do the trick.

Comment: Does not work when copying multiple lines, sadly. (Tested with html)

Comment: Correction: `"editor.formatOnPaste": false` works for me regardless of the autoIndent setting when I'm pasting html inside another html tag. However, when nesting html inside a jinja tag, nothing works regardless of editor.formatOnPaste and autoIndent.

Comment: thank you! `"editor.autoIndent": "none"` works for yml

Comment: great solution! I found that setting the `editor.autoIndent` option to `advanced` instead of `full` is enough to avoid the bug while copy pasting inside a html page

Answer (score 1):

On my own, I just disabled the PasteOnFormat and then paste my multiline codes with the regular Cmd+V. My headache is gone.

Comment: Note: answers that are very brief and/or are questions back to the poster should probably be comments. You only need 50 rep points to comment under a question - could you move this there?

Comment: @Tyler2P "You only need 50 rep points to comment" - true, but 1 is quite a bit less than 50.